# Preview in author instance

Tags: aem

Can I view my content in my author instance without the sidekick showing up? Can that be done without have a publish instance to view the content? I know there is a preview button on sidekick but that only minimizes sidekick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a parameter to your query string.

Just append `wcmmode=disabled`

For example: `http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html?wcmmode=disabled`

This will hide all of the authoring tools. It's as close as you can get to how a page looks on a publish on an author instance.

Be sure to remove `cf#` from the path.

Answer (score 1):

Think this link will be useful for you [CQ Developer Tricks](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/cq_developer_tricks/)

> ?wcmmode=(edit|preview|design|disabled)
>
> This para­me­ter sets your WCMMode in the spec­i­fied mode, makes test­ing for a par­tic­u­lar Wcm­Mode easier.

Answer (score 0):

For editing mode you can use

```
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html?wcmmode=edit
```

for preview mode it is

```
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html?wcmmode=preview
```

Comment: The sidekick is not hidden in the preview mode. It's only minimized. The OP actually mentioned the preview mode in the question.